# How to relatively position \pics in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code creates two kinds of `\pic` styles. The goal is to position the `\pic`s in such a way that the vertically opposite ovals are 1em apart and horizontally adjacent ovals are 1em apart. (The latter can of course only hold for the row in which the ovals are horizontally nearest - the ovals in the other row can be further apart due to the vertical alignment).

Positioning the `\pic`s relatively to each other with `right=of` and `below=of` goes terribly wrong. Absolute positioning also doesn't seem to work, because the width of the ovals is unknown (imagine the code is reused with other text values in the ovals).

How can the `\pic`s be positioned correctly?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,fit,shapes}
\tikzset {
  factor/.style = {draw, ellipse},
  indicator/.style = {draw, rectangle, outer sep=0},
  arr/.style={-latex},
  pics/collDown/.style n args={2}{
    code={%
      \node[indicator] ({#1}1) {{#1}};
      \node[factor, above=2em of {#1}1] (#1) {#2};
      \draw[arr] (#1) -- ({#1}1.north);
    }
  },
  pics/collUp/.style n args={2}{
    code={%
      \node[indicator] ({#1}1) {{#1}};
      \node[factor, below=2em of {#1}1] (#1) {#2};
      \draw[arr] (#1) -- ({#1}1.south);
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic[local bounding box=a] {collUp={A}{Some text}};
  \pic[local bounding box=b, right=1em of a] {collUp={B}{More text}};
  \pic[local bounding box=c, below=1em of a] {collDown={C}{Weird stuff}};
  \pic[local bounding box=d, below=1em of b] {collDown={D}{I'm giving up}};
  \pic at (0,-5) {collUp={A}{Some text}};
  \pic at (3,-5) {collUp={B}{More text}};
  \pic at (0,-9) {collDown={C}{Weird stuff}};
  \pic at (3,-9) {collDown={D}{I'm giving up}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Diagrams]

Comment: I see that all are `node`s. Why did you use `pic` ?

Comment: @BlackMild: I would like to reuse the code for `collUp` and `collDown`, but still be able to do the relative positioning. While googling, I only found `pic`s as a way to do that. Do you know alternatives?

Comment: I have just post an alternative answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an excellent question, and there is a very simple way to achieve this: wrap the `pic` in a matrix (with one entry). You can also write a macro for that, called `\ppic` below.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,fit,shapes}
\tikzset {
  factor/.style = {draw, ellipse},
  indicator/.style = {draw, rectangle, outer sep=0},
  arr/.style={-latex},
  pics/collDown/.style n args={2}{
    code={%
      \node[indicator] ({#1}1) {{#1}};
      \node[factor, above=2em of {#1}1] (#1) {#2};
      \draw[arr] (#1) -- ({#1}1.north);
    }
  },
  pics/collUp/.style n args={2}{
    code={%
      \node[indicator] ({#1}1) {{#1}};
      \node[factor, below=2em of {#1}1] (#1) {#2};
      \draw[arr] (#1) -- ({#1}1.south);
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[matrix] (a){\pic {collUp={A}{Some text}};\\};
  \node[matrix,right=1em of a] (b) {\pic {collUp={B}{More text}};\\};
  \node[matrix,below=1em of a] (c){\pic{collDown={C}{Weird stuff}};\\};
  \node[matrix,below=1em of b]  (d){\pic{collDown={D}{I'm giving up}};\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\ppic}[2][]{
\node[matrix,#1]{\pic{#2};\\ };}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \ppic[local bounding box=a] {collUp={A}{Some text}};
  \ppic[local bounding box=b, right=1em of a] {collUp={B}{More text}};
  \ppic[local bounding box=c, below=1em of a] {collDown={C}{Weird stuff}};
  \ppic[local bounding box=d, below=1em of b] {collDown={D}{I'm giving up}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If it bothers you that the rectangles are not aligned, you may want to unify the sizes of the ovals.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,fit,shapes}
\newbox\eqnodebox
\tikzset{equal size/.style={execute at begin
    node={\setbox\eqnodebox=\hbox\bgroup\vphantom{Hg}},
    execute at end node={\egroup\eqmakebox[#1][c]{\copy\eqnodebox}}},
    equal size/.default=A,
  factor/.style = {draw, ellipse,equal size},
  indicator/.style = {draw, rectangle, outer sep=0},
  arr/.style={-latex},
  pics/collDown/.style n args={2}{
    code={%
      \node[indicator] ({#1}1) {{#1}};
      \node[factor, above=2em of {#1}1] (#1) {#2};
      \draw[arr] (#1) -- ({#1}1.north);
    }
  },
  pics/collUp/.style n args={2}{
    code={%
      \node[indicator] ({#1}1) {{#1}};
      \node[factor, below=2em of {#1}1] (#1) {#2};
      \draw[arr] (#1) -- ({#1}1.south);
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[matrix] (a){\pic {collUp={A}{Some text}};\\};
  \node[matrix,right=1em of a] (b) {\pic {collUp={B}{More text}};\\};
  \node[matrix,below=1em of a] (c){\pic{collDown={C}{Weird stuff}};\\};
  \node[matrix,below=1em of b]  (d){\pic{collDown={D}{I'm giving up}};\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `equal size` node style takes a parameter, which can be thought of as an indicator/label. All node groups having the same label will have the same width.

Comment: Thank you, the matrix trick indeed solves the problem with the relative positioning! One detail is bothering me, though: the C and D rectangles (called indicators in the code) are no longer horizontally aligned. Is that because I'm using `pic`s?

Comment: @Jeroen This trick wraps the pic in a matrix node, and positioning will make sure that the distance between the node boundaries is what the user wants it to be, `1em` in this case. You can of course make sure that the `C` and `D` nodes are aligned by designing the pic in such a way that the vertical space above them is the same. This can be achieved by making the ellipses all the same size. If you specify a prescription I could add it to the answer.

Comment: Is there another way to achieve the exact same behavior as the matrix nesting gives us? Otherwise it runs into issues the first time you try to use this trick multiple pics deep and the matrix is nested

Answer (score 4):

After the above comment of OP, I suggest the below code (Is it the simplest?). A simple figure should be drawn by a simple code. All are nodes with absolute positioning, but parameters `\a`, `b`, `\h` make code flexible, that is, one can easily control distance as desired. Magenta lines is for checking horizontal alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\def\a{3.5} \def\b{4} \def\h{1.2}
\path[every node/.style={draw}]
(0,0)    node (A) {A}
(\a,0)   node (B) {B}
(0,-\b)  node (C) {C}
(\a,-\b) node (D) {D};
\path[every node/.style={draw,ellipse}]
(A)+(-90:\h) node (At) {Some text}
(B)+(-90:\h) node (Bt) {More text}
(C)+(90:\h)  node (Ct) {Weird stuff}
(D)+(90:\h)  node (Dt) {I'm giving up};

\foreach \p in {A,B,C,D} \draw[->] (\p t)--(\p);

% check for horizontal alignment
\draw[cyan] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\draw[thin,magenta,shorten >=-1.2cm,shorten <=-1.2cm] 
(A.base)--(B.base) (C.base)--(D.base)
(At.base)--(Bt.base) (Ct.base)--(Dt.base);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update** A bit shorter code as Kpym's suggested.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\def\a{3.5} \def\b{4} \def\h{1.2}
\path[nodes=draw]
(0,0)    node (A) {A} +(-90:\h) node[ellipse] (At) {Some text}
(\a,0)   node (B) {B} +(-90:\h) node[ellipse] (Bt) {More text}
(0,-\b)  node (C) {C} +(90:\h)  node[ellipse] (Ct) {Weird stuff}
(\a,-\b) node (D) {D} +(90:\h)  node[ellipse] (Dt) {I'm giving up}; 
\foreach \p in {A,B,C,D} \draw[-stealth] (\p t)--(\p);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can replace `every node/.style={draw}` by `nodes={draw}` to make your code even shorter ;)

Comment: @Kpym Thank you! I have added an update code.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using the same `text depth` in all nodes

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,fit,shapes}
\tikzset {
  factor/.style = {draw, ellipse,text depth=0.2ex},
  indicator/.style = {draw, rectangle, outer sep=0,text depth=0.2ex},
  arr/.style={-latex},
  pics/collDown/.style n args={2}{
    code={%
      \node[indicator] ({#1}1) {{#1}};
      \node[factor, above=2em of {#1}1] (#1) {#2};
      \draw[arr] (#1) -- ({#1}1.north);
    }
  },
  pics/collUp/.style n args={2}{
    code={%
      \node[indicator] ({#1}1) {{#1}};
      \node[factor, below=2em of {#1}1] (#1) {#2};
      \draw[arr] (#1) -- ({#1}1.south);
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%  \pic[local bounding box=a] {collUp={A}{Some text}};
%  \pic[local bounding box=b, right=1em of a] {collUp={B}{More text}};
%  \pic[local bounding box=c, below=1em of a] {collDown={C}{Weird stuff}};
%  \pic[local bounding box=d, below=1em of b] {collDown={D}{I'm giving up}};
  \pic at (0,-5) {collUp={A}{Some text}};
  \pic at (3,-5) {collUp={B}{More text}};
  \pic at (0,-9) {collDown={C}{Weird stuff}};
  \pic at (3,-9) {collDown={D}{I'm giving up}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]